# Keeping track of outlined fonts in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, typefaces

I'm interested in best practices for keeping track of typefaces in an Illustrator project once the text is converted to outlines. Is information hidden somewhere I don't know about? I sometimes keep the original text on a hidden layer, but that bulks up the file a bit.

Your thoughts?

Thank you!

Comment: NO once you outline its outlined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good practice is simply saving the ready-to-print type-outlined file as the same name with something like _outlined added to it. That way you can always revert back to the non-outlined version to make easy changes or find out the font name